# Java EE. Client IP in service. Use EJBContext

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb

I have a project with 2 modules: Rest and Service.
I need a client IP in service module, but i can get it only in Rest module from Request.
I think about use EJBContext.getContextData() to provide this IP in other module.

In Rest i create:

```js
@Provider
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyContainerRequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

 @Context
 private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

 @Inject
 private ApplicationService applicationService;

 @Override
 public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
  try {
   applicationService.getEJBContext().getContextData().put("ipAddress", servletRequest.getRemoteAddr());
   applicationService.getEJBContext().getContextData().put("ipHost", servletRequest.getRemoteHost());
  } catch(Exception ingnore) {

  }
 }
}

@LocalBean
@Stateless
public class ApplicationService {

 @Resource
 private EJBContext ejbContext; 

 public EJBContext getEJBContext() {
  return ejbContext;
 }
}
```

If i use

> @Resource private EJBContext ejbContext;

in MyContainerRequestFilter - then ejbContext = null;

So, in my example

```
applicationService.getEJBContext().getContextData() - NullPointerException
```

Tell me what's wrong? Any idea's how i can do it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the EJB context within an EJB invocations only to pass data within an EJB invocation or lifecycle methods.

You can try this within your filter: usually, synchonrous calls are executed by the same thread. You can store the IP adress within the Filter in a ThreadLocal and access this when needed.

Please refer this post when you are doing so: [Stackoverflow: ThreadLocal usage in enterprise applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328464/threadlocal-usage-in-enterprise-application)